# Natural Deduction Proof: A ↔ B |- (C → A) → (C → B)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

In an attempt to prove the formula, I tried setting a hypothesis

```
C -> A
```

like the following

```
1   A <-> B             Premise
2   |C -> A         Hypothesis
3   |A -> B         1 (<->E)
4   |C -> B         1, 2, 3 (?????)
```

, but I don't know what rule to apply to support the forth line

```
|C -> B
```

, even though I do know that I can reach this conclusion by combining 1, 2, 3.

What rule goes in to the ????? in the parenthesis above?

Also, I assume that I can prove

```
(C → A) → (C → B)
```

if I prove

```
A -> B 
C -> A
```

, but how do I add

```
C ->
```

part to A and B?

I know that I can prove like if

```
A
```

is true, then

```
A V B
```

is true as well (VI rule)

Also, if

```
A
```

is true and

```
B
```

is true, then

```
A Ʌ B
```

is true as well (ɅI rule).

and in this proof I want to add

```
C ->
```

to A and B so it will be

```
(C -> A) -> (C -> B)
```

, but how can I do it? There are introduction rules like

```
(VI rule)
(ɅI rule)
```

, but it seems there is no rule like

```
(->I rule)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to see the steps using the Fitch format of the natural deduction proof. Here is how the [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) associated with the *forallx* text presents this:

[image]

Because one is trying to derive a conditional, assume the antecedent of the conditional which is what is done on line 2.

The consequent of the conditional is also a conditional. So assume the antecedent, $C$, of that conditional, $C \to B$. This was done one line 3.

Line 4 uses conditional elimination (→E) to derive $A$ referencing lines 2 and 3.

Line 5 uses biconditional elimination (↔E) to derive *B* referencing lines 1 and 4.

Note that $B$ is what we want to derive given the assumption of $C$ on line 3. At this point we can proceed with conditional introduction (→I) used twice to derive the desired goal.

Since there was some concern about the existence of the conditional introduction rule, see section 15.3 in the *forallx* text linked to below for a discussion of the conditional and the associated introduction and elimination rules.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Oh yes that's really clear and easy to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative proof using mainly (1) conditional proof and (2) contraposition.

It also makes use of the replacement rule : (X --> Y) :: ~ ( X & ~Y)

as definition of the material implication operator.

The strategy is as follows :

(1) since the desired conclusion is a conditional statement ( having itself conditional statements as antecedent and consequent, but that does not matter), and since a conditional statement is always equivalent to its contrapositive statement ( the contrapositive of X --> Y is  ~ Y --> ~ X) , one can prove a conditional by proving its contrapositive ;

(2) the contrapositive of the desired conclusion is :

```
                 ~ ( C --> B)  -->  ~ ( C --> A)
```

(3) in order to prove this contrapositive, we use conditional proof, by assuming the antecedent, and deriving the consequent under this assumption.

(4) finally, we use  contraposition to recover the desired conclusion ( for the contrapositive of the contrapositive of X is X itself, or, in other words, the relation " being the contrapositive of " is a symmetric relation).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple : you have to use the [$(→ \text I)$](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) rule.

The first part of your proof is correct :

1) $A ↔ B$ --- premise

2) $C → A$ --- assumed [a]

3) $C$ --- assumed [b]

4) $A → B$ --- from 1) by $(↔ \text E)$

5) $A$ --- from 3) and 2) by $(→ \text E)$

6) $B$ --- from 5) and 4) by $(→ \text E)$

> 7) $C → B$ --- from 3) and 6) by $(→ \text I)$, discharging [b]
>
> > 8) $(C → A) \to (C → B)$ --- from 2) and 7) by $(→ \text I)$, discharging [a].

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yeah it makes sense, but how does it lead to the final conclusion (C → A) → (C → B)?

Comment: @ShinichiTakagi - Do you know the $(\to \text I)$ rule ? I've linked an explanation of it in my answer.

Comment: Oh now I think I get it. C -> A is assumed, so if C -> B is either assumed or proven, then I can combine (C -> A) and (C -> B) by (->I) rule, which becomes (C → A) → (C → B), right?